# Removing query strings in htaccess with conditions

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-redirect

I'm about ready to pull my hair out on this.  Basically, I've changed an old .asp site (that used queries for products) to a .php site (that also uses queries, but for different parameters).  Trying to get my htaccess redirects to work. The bottom line is that I need to pull the query strings out at certain times, but not others.

Here is the form of the old URL for a product, product ID in this case being "101":
     http://www.example.com/shopping/shopexd.asp?id=101

There were a lot of products, and as my new site does not use queries for products, so I just want to redirect them all to my new home page.

If I use something like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/shopping/(.*) http://www.example.com/
```

Then it leaves the ?=101 at the end, giving me:

```
http://www.example.com/?=101
```

I can't use a blanket "get rid of all queries" type of approach because the new site does use them for other things, like order ids or category ids.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use mod_rewrite rule to strip existing query string.

put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^shopping/ http://www.mysite.com/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Here `?` in the end is used to strip off any existing query string.